# React not rendering anything in Spring application (using frontend-maven-plugin)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring, maven

I´m using frontend-maven-plugin in a Spring Data REST application to use React as the front end library. Once I execute the Main application, I go to localhost:8080. Inside the Logo and the title in the index.html "ReactJS + Spring Data REST" appears correctly, so i´m assuming the app is correctly reading the index.html, but nothing of the boilerplate of React appears.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <!-- The title does appear correctly: -->
    <title>ReactJS + Spring Data REST</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div id="react"></div>

    <script src="built/bundle.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

```js
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
const client = require('./client');

function App(){
  return (
   <div>
                {/* This doesn´t appear: */}
    <h3>Trying React in Spring</h3>
   </div>
  )
 }
}


ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.getElementById('react'))
```

I don´t have any errors in the proyect. I honestly don´t know where could be the problem.
Here´s the error in the devtools appears: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()bundle.js"

Here´s how my files are structured right now:

[image]

Comment: Should the source for the js files be `src="build/bundle.js"`?

Comment: open dev tools in browser and check is there any error

Comment: Right: Here´s the error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()bundle.js:1 I´ll update it to the original post

Comment: @Clarity I´m not sure. I´m following a tutorial, right now my App of react is in "App.js" file and in the folder "js" which is in the same level as the folder "java"